# useStaticQuery does not support variables; how then to organise my gatsby app to allow a postlist component to show posts from a specific category

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I have the following graphql query code in a postlist component which lists all posts on an index page. The idea is that depending if the user is at music, style or art urls a different set of posts would be displayed by using a filter.

```
const PostList = ({category}) => {
  console.log(category);
    const data = useStaticQuery(graphql` 
      query PostListQuery {
        allSanityArticle(
          filter: {category: {title: {eq: "music"}}}
          sort: {publishedAt: DESC}
          ) {
          edges {
            node {
              title
              titleJA
              mainImage {
                asset {
                  publicUrl
                  gatsbyImageData
                }
              }
              category {
                title
              }
              slug {
                current
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }`,
      );
```

I'd like to use the `category` prop to filter `category>title`. This is my first time using Gatsby or react/javascript and now that I've actually built the bulk of the app, I think I've come to realise why useStaticQuery has this name! It seems I can't actually pass a variable to the query at all (I've tried various things) and have recently read that it goes against the rule of hooks?

Is there way to do what I want? Assuming this isn't possible, how do you recommend I reorganise the app to allow for this?

Would the idea be to always plan to do dynamic queries at the page level instead and pass any necessary data down to the components? If this is a best practice, then what is the point in having static queries for components at all?

Thanks for any advice you can give, trying to get a wider understanding of how to plan and build apps with this framework.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.